# Is there a way to incorporate CSP into flask admin for its generated inline js?

Tags: flask, hash, content-security-policy, flask-admin, nonce

I'm trying to incorporate CSP (Content Security Policy) into the flask admin framework and keep running into issues. Due to the js being generated, I was wondering if there was a simple way to attach a nonce to all generated scripts without having to manually overwrite every template.

I currently have the following nonce code in the system:

```
@app.before_request
    def renew_nonce():
        nonce = secrets.token_hex(32)
        g.nonce = nonce


    @app.context_processor
    def get_nonce():
        # Return a dictionary containing the nonce value
        nonce = g.nonce
        return {'nonce': nonce}
    
    @app.after_request
    def apply_security_headers(response):
        """Setting security headers"""
        # Generate a random nonce value
        nonce = g.nonce
        print("nonce after request: ", nonce)
        response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains'
        response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = f"default-src 'self'; \
            script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajaxorg.github.io 'nonce-{nonce}'; \
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; \
            img-src 'self' api.mapbox.com data:; \
            connect-src 'self'; \
            worker-src 'self' blob:;"
        response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
        response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
        response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '1; mode=block'
        return response
```

This generates the nonce for me to use in the templates for the code that I overwrite. However, is there anyway to attach the nonce to the js generated by the flask admin framework?

Example of how I use the nonce in the jinja2 framework:

```
<script nonce = "{{ nonce }}">
        //Does stuff
    </script>
```

Comment: very useful peace of code. tx

Comment: Everyone, just a heads up. It's best to just modify every template.

Comment: Why? I use about the sam ecode using blueprints an dseems to work very well. Are you talking best for security reasons? tx