# flask-talisman use js scripts located in static/js/folders

Tags: flask, python-3.9, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement CSP using flask-talisman (new to that).
I managed to load external cdns but I can't use my own scripts located in /static/js/[folders]/[subfolders]/file.js
ex. in template html:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/leaflet_handlers/realtor_overlays.js') }}"></script>

<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}">
functionIn_realtor_overlays();

</script>
```

then at the functionIn_realtor_overlays() level, I get error: ip/...static/js/.../realtor_overlays.js " was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

my csp dict is:

```
tal_csp = {
    'default-src': ['\'self\'',
                    'https://unpkg.com', 'https://googletagmanager.com',
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com', 'https://code.jquery.com',
                    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com'
                    ],
    'script-src': ['\'self\'',
                   'https://unpkg.com', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com', 'https://code.jquery.com',
                   'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
                   ],

}
```

which I call at the app level liek this:

```
Talisman(app,
         content_security_policy=tal_csp,
         content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src']
         )
```

it seems that I may need to include a new key ('X-Content-Type-Options') in my tal_csp dict but I am not sure how and didn't find an example so far.
Any help would be greatly aprecaited thank you

NB: I currently run the app on Windows debug and then the prod will be on Ubuntu server, using difefrent ip/url/port to the static folder

Answer (score 0):

In case that helps others.

After further reading, this may be caused by a "bug" on Windows registry:
[link to flask github issues](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1045)
I had same issue whether I use Talisman to implement my CSP or do it myself ([see this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952649/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-csp-into-flask-admin-for-its-generated-inline-js#comment134680102_75952649).

I ended up using the bellow code before creating the app and it now seems to work as expected.

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')
mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
```

NB: I was running my app in debug mode on windows and use ubuntu/gunicon/nginx for prod.